# Can people's names be added to a URL slug?

Tags: seo, user-generated-content, url-slug

On webpages generated from user generated content, I create slugs for the URLs based on the title (just like Stack Overflow does):

```
http://www.example.com/photo/day_at_park
```

If there's more than one slug "day_at_park", I'll append a count:

```
http://www.example.com/photo/day_at_park,2
```

Does it make sense to include, in this example, names of people involved in the content?  So if it was a photo of Susan and Bob, the URL might be:

```
http://www.example.com/photo/day_at_park,susan_surandan,bob_smith
```

One benefit is far fewer chances of needing to append a count like the second example above.  The URLs also are more descriptive about the core parts of the content.

On the downside, the URLs are clearly longer.  And I have to introduce more ugly commas (though better than `-` or `_`).  If, in the above example, there are many people in a photo… I would have to cut down the slug size by removing people…  that seems inappropriate, basically attributing more SEO importance to arbitrary people.

Comment: If you put an ID in your URL, like Stack Overflow does, you can put anything you want after it, with or without the commas.  Compare [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265578/adding-names-to-slug-of-url#question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265578/adding-names-to-slug-of-url#question) with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265578 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/7265578

Comment: @Robert, yes I understand an ID allows me to put anything I want.  The question of whether to add names involved in the content still remains though.  Also, adding an ID is much worse from a length, aesthetic and SEO perspective than adding a duplicate count # isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You're over-valuing the "[keyword in the url](http://www.seomoz.org/article/search-ranking-factors#metrics-6)" impact for SEO purposes. Yes, all other things being equal having keyword may assist (they'll be useful to your visitors).
2. Don't use underscores in URLs. [Just don't](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQcSFsQyct8).
3. Don't use commas in URLs. [Just don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198606/can-i-use-commas-in-a-url/198850#198850). Hypenating the URL with -2 is much better.
4. Length of the URL is also not a radically large factor - except when you're differentiating 30 characters vs 230...

Comment: Wow, that was very surprising to see Matt Cutts say Google treats dashes as separators and underscores as joins.

Comment: That discussion has been ongoing for several years. The video I linked to was an update from his [earlier post in 2005](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/dashes-vs-underscores/)!